# Cocoapods framework cannot find file in another cocoapods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm working with a library installed via Cocoapods that depends on AFNetworking as a linked framework. After I installed the library, my project will not compile because imported AFNetworking files can not be found.

[image]

However, it seems that modules are causing the problem because if I change the import from:

`#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"`

to

`#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h>`

..the error disappears. I'd rather not go about changing code in these linked libraries, so how can I get my library to successfully find the AFNetworking files?

**EDIT** Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Motospot' do

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
    pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.1'
    pod 'BDBOAuth1Manager'

end

target 'MotospotTests' do

end
```

Comment: did u try to follow this link :https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

Comment: can you post your Podfile?

Comment: Why don't you add `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` to your prefix header file? You know `#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"` type is used for internal classes.

Comment: Did you add to your swift file "import AFNetworking" in a header?

Answer (score 8):

Please check the profile - AFNetworking version

Change to

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
```

and use

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I succeed in configuring AFNetworking with swift. This is the Podfile:

## Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!  
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

## Bridge_AFNetworking.h

```
#ifndef eShop_Bridge_AFNetworking_h
#define eShop_Bridge_AFNetworking_h

#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

#endif
```

This is some sample code using AFNetworking.

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking

class DataManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = DataManager()

    let manager:AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    override init() {

        super.init()

    }

}
```

Comment: I found my answer in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

Copy the framework and delete it. If the problem persists, go to framework and library's and drag the file there. That should make the file visible by all other files then go back and try importing

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was:

1. Close Xcode
2. Remove the Pods directory from the project ROOT
3. In terminal cd to project ROOT and then "pod install --verbose"
4. Open xcode from xcworkspace file
5. Build